# Confusion on looping array of objects using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have data like this,

```
var menuItems = {  
   "titles":[  
      {  
         "title_id":"Chief Information Officer (CIO)",
         "title_name":"Chief Information Officer (CIO)"
      },
      {  
         "_title_id":"Chief Technology Officer (CTO)",
         "title_name":"Chief Technology Officer (CTO)"
      }
   ],
   "skills":[  
      {  
         "skill_id":1000185,
         "skill_name":"ITSoftware Development"
      },
      {  
         "skill_id":1000186,
         "skill_name":"Network Security"
      }
   ]
};
```

I want to loop through all the data and append the values to select box options values and names. So for testing I'm using the following jQuery,

```
$.each(menuItems, function (key, value) {
        {
            if (key == "titles") {
                $.each(value, function (key1, value1) {

                    for(k in value1) {
                       $('.title-append').append($('<option>', {
                                                value: value1[k],
                                                text: value1[k]
                       }));

                    }
                })
            }
        }
        });
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<select name="position" class="form-control title-append" id="position"><option value="">Select..</option></select>
```

All the values are appended twice in select box. I'm stuck here, I tried different cases but nothing seem to work. Is it anything wrong with the jQuery?

[image]

Comment: You have no JSON here, just arrays and objects. JSON is just a string/text format. By the time you're doing `$.each` on it, it's been parsed.

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery necessary:

```js
var menuItems = {
  "titles": [{
      "title_id": "Chief Information Officer (CIO)",
      "title_name": "Chief Information Officer (CIO)"
    },
    {
      "title_id": "Chief Technology Officer (CTO)",   // <-- you had a typo in this key
      "title_name": "Chief Technology Officer (CTO)"
    }
  ],
  "skills": [{
      "skill_id": 1000185,
      "skill_name": "ITSoftware Development"
    },
    {
      "skill_id": 1000186,
      "skill_name": "Network Security"
    }
  ]
};

// retrieve the select
var dropdown = document.getElementById('position');

// iterate over array
menuItems['titles'].forEach(obj => {
  var option = document.createElement('option');  // create a new option
      option.value = obj.title_id;                // set the value attribute
      option.textContent = obj.title_name;        // set what's displayed
  dropdown.appendChild(option);                   // attach to document
});
```

```html
<select name="position" class="form-control title-append" id="position">
  <option value="">Select..</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why anybody would like to change his structure when prob has simple solution...?

Comment: @user7417866 perhaps you are down voting me because I am using a new account? If so, you are misguided.  **(1)** IE does support a lot of ES6 (after all it's only an extension of ES5 and not a completely new language); Microsoft Edge will almost fully-support it **(2)** There's no structure change VanillaJS is more efficient and just as simple as jQuery (as I have proven above)

Comment: no its not because you are new, its because you are suggesting to change structure of question when it is not required and simple tweak can solve the problem. And not all users will have Edge, it should minimum support IE 10 as standard (if so, my apologies for ES6 comment, I've removed it anyways)

Comment: **(3)** This is a demo and I'm not writing his program, he can use this as a learning tool for his answer, but arrow functions are really easy to convert from `( key => { … })` to `(function(key){ … })` if he cares **(4)** You took the comment down, but never suggest because something isn't fully-supported, it isn't a good solution; the language and browsers are updated at various times, you may never find something that is fully supported.

Comment: Just to clarify @user7417866 would like to discourage others because their answer wasn't his :P Sorry you feel that way

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only processing titles, you should just iterate `menuItems.titles` instead of the entire `menuItem` object:

```
menuItems.titles.forEach(function(title) {
    $('.title-append').append($('<option>', {
        value: title.title_id,
        text: title.title_name,
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simplify your iterate over your json,

as long as you are iterate over specific key 'titles', iterate directly over it by providing it as the array which you want to iterate over it.

```
$.each(menuItems['titles'], function(key, value) {
    $('.title-append').append($('<option>', {value: value['title_id'],text: value1['title_name']}));
});
```

Answer (score -2):

you need not to have inner for loop, since your value1 object will already have 2 object and your for with each will loop it to 4, try this way..

```js
   

 $(function(){
    var menuItems = {  
       "titles":[  
          {  
             "title_id":"Chief Information Officer (CIO)",
             "title_name":"Chief Information Officer (CIO)"
          },
          {  
             "title_id":"Chief Technology Officer (CTO)",
             "title_name":"Chief Technology Officer (CTO)"
          }
       ],
       "skills":[  
          {  
             "skill_id":1000185,
             "skill_name":"ITSoftware Development"
          },
          {  
             "skill_id":1000186,
             "skill_name":"Network Security"
          }
       ]
    };

    $.each(menuItems, function (key, value) {
            {
                if (key == "titles") {
                    $.each(value, function (key1, value1) {
                           $('.title-append').append($('<option>', {
                                                    value: value1.title_id,
                                                    text: value1.title_name
                           }));
                    })
                }
if (key == "skills") {
                    $.each(value, function (key1, value1) {
                           $('.student-append').append($('<option>', {
                                                    value: value1.skill_Id,
                                                    text: value1.skill_name
                           }));
                    })
                }
            }
            });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="position" class="form-control title-append" id="position"><option value="">Select..</option></select>
<select name="Students" class="form-control student-append" id="Students"><option value="">Select..</option></select>
```